# Composer - Drush - You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php, drush

I hope you can help me on this one. I'm trying ton install drush on Windows 8 using Composer. So I execute this command line:

```
composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

And composer return this error:

> You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

I modified my php.ini files and set the extension activated. I restarted my server, my cmd. But nothing to do, still get this error.
Any solutions?

(Sorry for the mistakes, Frenchman in place.)

Comment: have you opened this one extension=php_openssl.dll ??

Comment: extension=php_openssl.dll
Yep

Comment: If you use php-fpm, try restarting the fpm server process.